# Find the value of $(\tan35°+\tan55°)(\sin35°+\sin55°+1)(\cos35°+\cos55°+1)$

Tags: trigonometry

I did Prostapherisis and got 
$\frac{1}{\sin70°}+4\cos20°+4$. What I should do now? The answer is a number "beatiful", like 1,$\sqrt3$, I just know this.

Comment: In MathJax, you get tangent with \tan, not \tg.  I have no clue what Prostapherisis is

Comment: Suppose $x=\sin 35^\circ$ and $y=\sin 55^\circ$.  Then the expression becomes $$\left(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}\right)(x+y+1)^2=\frac{(x^2+y^2)(x+y+1)^2}{xy}.$$

Comment: In your work, note that $\sin70^\circ=\cos20^\circ$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from @Quanto's answer
$$A=2 \cot \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\pi }{2}-a\right)\right) \cot
   \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)=2+\frac{4}{\sin (a)+\cos (a)-1}$$ 
If $a$ was $36°=\frac \pi 5$, the problem would be "simple" and the result would be
$$2 \left(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{2 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)\approx 12.0806$$

To have a better *approximation*, develop $A$ as a Taylor series around  $\epsilon=0$ with $a=\frac \pi 5$ 
$$2+\frac{4}{\sin (a-\epsilon)+\cos (a-\epsilon)-1}=\left(2+\frac{4}{\sin (a)+\cos (a)-1}\right)+\frac{4   (\cos (a)-\sin
   (a))}{(\sin (a)+\cos (a)-1)^2}\epsilon-\frac{2  (\sin (a)+\sin (2 a)+\cos
   (a)-3)}{(\sin (a)+\cos (a)-1)^3}\epsilon ^2+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$ Replacing, this gives
$$2 \left(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{2 \left(5+\sqrt{5}\right)}\right)+\left(6 \sqrt{5}-6-2 \sqrt{50-22 \sqrt{5}} \right)\epsilon-\left(15 \sqrt{5}-31+\sqrt{2210-838 \sqrt{5}}\right)\epsilon ^2+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$

Now, make $\epsilon=\frac \pi{180}$ and computing, you would get
$12.18504$ while the "exact" solution is $12.18515$

**Edit**

Thanks to the containment, I have been able to find the exact formula writing
$$1+\frac 4{A-2}=\sin(a)+\cos(a)$$ and used the fact that
$$\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{5}-\epsilon \right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{5}-\epsilon \right)=$$ $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) (-1)^{4/5} \left((-1)^{9/10}
   (-i)^n-i^n\right)}{n!} \epsilon^n=$$
$$-\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right) (-1)^{4/5} e^{-i \epsilon }
   \left(e^{2 i \epsilon }-(-1)^{9/10}\right)$$ which makes
$$A=2+\frac{4(1+ i) e^{i \epsilon }}{-(1+i) e^{i \epsilon }+(-1)^{3/10} e^{2 i \epsilon
   }+(-1)^{1/5}}$$ and the fraction is equal to
$$\frac{16}{\left(-1-\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{10-2 \sqrt{5}}\right) \sin (\epsilon
   )+\left(1+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{10-2 \sqrt{5}}\right) \cos (\epsilon )-4}$$ where $\epsilon=\frac \pi{180}$.

We know the exact value of $\sin ({1}^{\circ})$ and $\cos ({1}^{\circ})$ (have a look [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-value-of-sin1%C2%B0-1)). So, the **exact** result !

Answer (score 1):

Let $a = 35°$. Then,

$$\begin{align}
& (\tan35°+\tan55°)(\sin35°+\sin55°+1)(\cos35°+\cos55°+1) \\
& =\frac{\tan^2a+1}{\tan a}\cdot(\sin a + \cos a + 1)^2 \\
& =\frac1{\sin a\cos a}\cdot 2(1 + \sin a\cos a+\sin a + \cos a) \\
& =2\cdot \frac{(1+\sin a)(1+\cos a)}{\sin a\cos a} \\
& =2\cdot \frac{\cos a}{1-\sin a} \cdot \frac{1+\cos a}{\sin a} \\
& =2\cdot \frac{\sin (90^\circ-a)}{2\sin^2(45^\circ-\frac a2)} \cdot\frac{2\cos^2 \frac a2}{2\sin \frac a2\cos\frac a2} \\
& =2\cdot \frac{\cos(45^\circ-\frac a2)\cos \frac a2}{\sin(45^\circ-\frac a2)\sin\frac a2} \\
&= 2\cot \frac{55^\circ}2\cot \frac{35^\circ}2 \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Impressive.  I should have tried harder but I was only interested in showing the OP's result did not equal the given expression.

Comment: There is an exact solution !! It took me hours. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your result doesn't numerically match the original expression.  Your value is about $8.8$; the original expression has value approximately $12.1852$.

I do not have a closed-form solution for your expression, but it is a root of the sextic $$x^6+36 x^5-324 x^4-3104 x^3-1296 x^2+576 x+64 = 0.$$

Comment: Could you please explain how we can obtain the sextic equation with that exact root?

Comment: There is an exact solution !! It took me hours. Cheers :-)